# Scrolling tables horizontally with Bootstap 3 - Opera Mini/mobile

Tags: theming

I'm having issues on opera(mini/mobile) with scrolling an table horizontally. I am using bootstrap 3 as a theme. My table markup is as follows:

I am using the following CSS:

.table-responsive {
    width: 100%; 
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    overflow-x: auto !important; 
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important; 
 }

The scrolling works on all other browsers I tested, just Opera that not playing nicely

PS: I notice same issue on the bootstrap project page:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Doesn't work, any pointers or workarounds please!

Comment: Found an workaround. By installing this module - https://drupal.org/project/browserclass i was able to inject browser specific classes into my body tag and style my table cells to stack just on opera.

Comment: 2 years later, Opera Mini still doesn't seem to support `overflow-x`.